# Expected a typeがよく分からない

Tags: objective-c

■C++クラスヘッダ→Test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include "TestDef.h"
void Test(TEST_STR& test_str);
#endif     // TEST_H
```

■C++デファインヘッダ→TestDef.h

```
#ifndef TESTDEF_H
#define TESTDEF_H
struct TEST_STR {
    int a;
    int b;
};
#endif
```

■C＋＋クラス→Test.cppをTest.mmにしました。

```
#include "Test.h"
#include "TestDef.h"

void Test(TEST_STR& test_str)
{
}
```

■Obje-c++ヘッダ→TestObj.h

```
#ifndef TestObj_h
#define TestObj_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestDef.h"
@interface TestObj : NSObject    
- (void) test:(TEST_STR&)test ;
@end

#endif /* TestObj_h */
```

■Obj-C++ソース→TestObj.mm

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestObj.h"
#import "Test.h"

@implementation TestObj

- (void) test:(TEST_STR&)a {
    Test(a);
}

@end
```

■ブリッジファイルに`#import "TestObj.h"`を入れています。

このような感じなのですが、
■Obje-c++ヘッダの下記の箇所で「Expected a type」が出てしまいます。

```
- (void) test:(TEST_STR&)test ;
```

上記エラーを検索すると、#import の追加がいるような記載があったため、そちらも追加してみましたが
変わらず・・・
XCODEからTEST_STRにジャンプもできたので参照できていると
思うのですが何がおかしいのかさっぱりわかりません。
ご助言いただけると助かります。

Answer (score 1):

(ご自身で書かれているように「#import の追加がいる」ような状態では各ファイルがどのようにimportされているかが重要になってきますので「C++クラスヘッダ」のようなファイルの概要の説明だけでなく、それらがどんなファイル名なのかも記載された方が良いでしょう。＞追記ありがとうございます。追記に関わる修正は下の方に。)

こちらでは、ご掲載のコードを以下のようなファイル名のファイルに置くと、コンパイルが通ってしまいます。

- C++クラスヘッダ -> Test.h
- C++デファインヘッダ -> TestDef.h
- C＋＋クラス -> Test.cpp
- Obje-c++ヘッダ -> TestObj.h
- Obj-C++ソース -> TestObj.mm

「C＋＋クラス（mm拡張子に変更）」と書かれていますが、「Obj-C++ソース」の方の拡張子を.mmにしないと、そこからimportされているTestObj.h内ではC++データ型が使えなくなってしまいます。再度各ファイル名やimportを含むファイル内容を確認してみてください。

[追記]
ご質問内の追記内容と私の上記内容を見比べると

- C＋＋クラス -> Test.cppをTest.mmにしました。

という部分で違いがあるのですが、これは問題になりません。「C＋＋クラス」の中ではC++の機能しか使われていませんので、"C++"としてコンパイルしても"Objective-C++"としてコンパイルしても、結果は同じになります。

影響しているのはこちらのようですね。

- ブリッジファイルに「#import "TestObj.h"」を入れています。

Xcodeでプロジェクトを作成された時にSwiftプロジェクトとして作成されたものにC++ファイルや、Objective-C++ファイルを追加されたのでしょうか。Swiftプロジェクトのビルドの過程でBridging-Headerを参照する場合、その内容は(Objective-C++ではなく)Objective-C用のヘッダとして解釈されます。従ってその中ではC++の参照型は型(type)としては認識されないものになるため、その際に"Expected a type"になってしまっているのでしょう。

C++で書かれた関数の機能をSwiftから利用するためにObjective-C++でそのwrapperクラスを作成するといった場合、Swift側に読み込ませたいクラスの@interface部分ではC++の機能を使ってはいけません。
　例えば、Swift側には(参照型ではなく)ポインターでやりとりするというのが一つの手でしょう。

■Obj-c++ヘッダ→TestObj.h

```
#ifndef TestObj_h
#define TestObj_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestDef.h"
@interface TestObj : NSObject
- (void) test:(TEST_STR*)test ;
@end

#endif /* TestObj_h */
```

■Obj-C++ソース→TestObj.mm

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "TestObj.h"
#import "Test.h"

@implementation TestObj

- (void) test:(TEST_STR*)a {
    Test(*a);
}

@end
```

上記のままでは、まだエラーが出るようですね。TEST_STR型の定義は"C++"としても"C"としても通るような書き方をする必要があります。

■C++デファインヘッダ→TestDef.h

```
#ifndef TESTDEF_H
#define TESTDEF_H
typedef struct TEST_STR {
    int a;
    int b;
} TEST_STR;
#endif
```

いかがでしょうか。何かありましたらまたご報告ください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます！
ファイル名を追記しました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。このあと追記に合わせて回答の方を修正しておきます。

Comment: 「Xcodeでプロジェクトを作成された時にSwiftプロジェクトとして作成されたものにC++ファイルや、Objective-C++ファイルを追加されたのでしょうか。」
まさに、その通りでした。
typedefを付けなければ、C,C++両方で通らない・・・そんなことも忘れていました。
すごく勉強になりました。
エラーが出た時解析が難しく、ここじゃないか？というあてがなかなか浮かばない状態です…
大変勉強になりました！